# Azure Service Principal gets "Authorization_RequestDenied" when used in Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-cli, azure-service-principal

I have a service principal that is used when running my Terraform scripts that works for 99% of what I need to do. However I then need to run the following script with terraform to update a property on an App Registration - as this is the only way it can be done (Here for reference - https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azuread/issues/188).

```
resource "null_resource" "access_token_accepted_version" {
   depends_on = [
   azuread_application.appname
]
provisioner "local-exec" {
command = <<EOF
  az login --service-principal --username ${var.az_client_id} --password 
${var.az_client_secret} --tenant ${var.az_tenant_id}
  az rest \
    --method PATCH \
    --headers "Content-Type=application/json" \
    --uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/${azuread_application.appname.id}" \
    --body '{"api":{"requestedAccessTokenVersion":2}}'
EOF
  }
}
```

The Az login part seems to run successfully, but then the PATCH call will always result in the following error -

```
ERROR: Forbidden({"error":{"code":"Authorization_RequestDenied","message":"Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."
```

I would like to think there is a permission I can add to the associated app registration for the service principal, but I cannot find the right one. Here is what I have currently (some are needed, some are stabs in the dark)

[image]

Can anyone think of a way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to give `Application.ReadWrite.All` permission under `Microsoft Graph`. Currently you have given that permission under `Azure Active Directory Graph`.

Once you do that, you should not get this error.

Comment: Thanks this worked perfectly! I have that permission under the deprecated Azure Active Directory Graph because I believe it's still needed there by terraform, but didn't consider I would need it under both. Thanks again!